# Setting Env variable on linux through ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh, environment-variables

Hi guys Im stuck here about 5 hours and cant make it work. The last thing I tried was

Creating a .bat file that invokes a .sh file that uses a .data file in order to try to setup an environment variable on an ubuntu remote machine.

My .bat goes like this:

```
@echo off

set SSH_USER=remoteMachineUser
set SSH_HOST=remoteMachineIP

ssh %SSH_USER%@%SSH_HOST% "chmod +x /home/set_data.sh && cd /home/ && ./set_data.sh > /home/set_data.log 2>&1"
```

my .sh goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'export DATA=$(cat .data)' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

and .data contains the value I want to assign to the env variable.

The thing is once I execute 'env' in my ubuntu machine, after running the .bat. There is no any variable created.

I have also tried using a .jar like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java SetEnvironmentVariables <token>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String envVarValue = args[0];

        Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
        systemProperties.setProperty("DATA", envVarValue);
        System.out.println("I executed everything dude");
    }
}
```

I know the scripts are getting executed its but I can't see the changes reflected. I need this to be made remotely, I cannot do it manually. I'm starting to think its just impossible. I would be more than glad if someone can help me with it

Comment: Maybe `echo "export DATA=$(cat .data)" >> ~/.bashrc`  . Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter I tried with: echo "export DATA=$(cat .data)" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
echo "$DATA"
echo $DATA
 and also without the (source ~/.bashrc) but nothing only displays empty, and I ran it locally (not using ssh)

Comment: Please update your Q to include some sample values for what is in your `.data` file. Are you sure the script is executing in the correct dir so that it "sees" the `.data` file. Does using `echo "export DATA=$(cat /full/path/to/.data)" >> ~/bashrc` help? Good luck.

Comment: Otherwise, you need to figure which parts are working and which part arent. does a `.bat` file with just `ssh %SSH_USER%@%SSH_HOST% "echo ON REMOTE MACHINE"` work? If yes, keep adding elements but also test in isolation. Assuming you can `ssh` to the remote what happens when you execute that cmd line in a terminal session (putty?). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Im using this, now: echo ```"$(cat .data)"
echo "$(cat .data)" >> dummy2.log
echo "export DATASA=$(cat .data)" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc```

The data is a git token, and now it gets prompted and its correctly saved in dummy2.log. But after executing the .sh completely, if I type in the terminal "env" My env variable is not there. Im doing it locally Im not using ssh any more. I was thinking that I should make it work first through executing it locally and then trying the ssh way. But still does not work

Comment: Please add an **Edit** section at the bottom and include this comment with good formatting of the code. (Then we can delete some of our comments to reduce the amount other readers have to wade thru to understand your problem) You can make up a "test" git token so you don't leave your git open to exploit, but unless the real value is strictly alph-numeric (A-Za-z0-9), you'll have to include any shell meta characters to make the example testable. I can check back in an hour, but then it will be bed time, so you may not hear from me until tomorrow. Good luck.